# iptables: force clients to use proxy

Tags: linux, firewalls, proxy, iptables, squid

My network: 192.168.0.1 server. (enp0s3 NAT, enp0s8 internal) 192.168.0.10-15 clients (enp0s3 internal).

I have a proxysquid for blocking websites,and so on.

My clients can navigate and browse any website if no proxy is set at firefox settings, if I set the proxy they can't reach any website but can ping 8.8.8.8

My iptables for the conection are:

```
EXTERNA="enp0s3"
INTERNA="enp0s8"

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t nat -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# ALLOW TCP & UDP PROTOCOLS
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i $INTERNA -p tcp -m multiport --dports 53,80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i $INTERNA -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i $INTERNA -p tcp  --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# ALLOW NAT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTERNA -j MASQUERADE
```

To force clients I've tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INTERNA -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

And:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INTERNA -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT--to-destination 192.168.0.1:3128
```

The second one (-j DNAT), worked fine while I was using an ACCEPT default policy, but now I need to set the default policy to DROP, and it's not working anymore.

Honestly I'm a novice using iptables, and maybe the solution is easier than I think, but I need some help, thanks you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redirect traffics to the host itself, the chain of concern in the filter table would be `INPUT` instead of `FORWARD`, so add the necessary `ACCEPT` rules to the former instead. Also the port of concern would be the new port as well:

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i $INTERNA -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i $INTERNA -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i $INTERNA -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hi @Tom Yan, I feel a bit confused, honestly. Could you send my any correction of my script with the rules you think are the best? I don't really know how to fix it, I'm sorry.

Comment: I already did. Just replace the whole `# ALLOW TCP & UDP PROTOCOLS` block with the code block I've given you.

Comment: Thanks you so much Tom, It helped me a lot.